# cast primitive array to Object and back

Tags: java, arrays

I have this

```
int [] abc = new int[30];

Object arr = abc;
```

How do i cast `arr` back to `int[]` ?? ie

```
int [] foo = (int[])arr
```

Also, if arr could point to `int[]` or `byte[]`, how to distinguish them??

I've checked `arr.getClass().getName()` returns `[I`  and `arr.getClass().isPrimitive()` is `false`. Must be another way to detect it?

Thanks.

PS. I must use primitive types in my arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The casting is right, `(int[])arr` does the trick.

You can recognize the type by comparing the class objects, if you want:

```
if(arr.getClasS() == int[].class) {
    ...
}
```

or better

```
if(arr instanceof int[]) {
   ...
}
```

The `[I` class name is another way, but less clear in code.
You could also do `arr.getClass().getComponentType()`, which should return `int.class`.

Comment: good answer, but I cant help but to notice that your "or better" is an (arr instanceof ...) , you know that Gary Jules song.

Comment: I dont know your exact use case, but you might need to do an Class.isAssignableFrom instead of instanceof or equals check.

Comment: @Captain: I did not know this song (or heard the name Gary Jules before). Do you have some link?

Comment: @Ebermann Mad World, great song, still a mad world though. Youtubes first is the one.

Comment: @Ali: between primitive types (and their arrays) there is no inheritance relation, thus `isAssignableFrom` is not really useful. And in general, when you have an object, better use `c.isInstance(o)` instead of `c.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())`.