# int[] arr2 = arr1.clone() compiles without casting RHS (Object) to (int[]). Why derivedObj = baseObj allowed with no cast to Derived (i.e. int[])?

Tags: java, arrays, object

`int[]` is the type which is derived from `java.lang.Object` (subtype of it).
So it shall be prohibited to assign `int[] array = new Object()` (without casting) for same reason as I cannot write (without casting) `derivedObj = baseObj` (but I can write `derivedObj = (Derived) baseObj`).

Why the code below compiles (and works in runtime) fine? It shall give error that `Object` type returned by clone cannot be implicitly cast to subtype of `Object` (namely, `int[]`) without explicitly casting like `int[] ar2 = (int[]) ar1.clone();`, which also compiles and works fine.

```
    int[] ar1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    //now we assign Base class to Derived class without explicit cast
    int[] ar2 = ar1.clone(); // why no compile ERR here???
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar2)); // output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

but code below would fail to compile, and I understand why: we cannot cast from Base class to Derived class without explicit cast (thinking of int[] as subclass of Object).

```
Object obj = new Object();
ar2 = obj; // c.ERR!! cannot convert from Object to int[]
```

MY GUESS IS LIKE THIS: **clone() is overridden in primitive arrays to return not Object, but subclass of Object, so int[].clone() returns int[] !!!**  It is possible for overriden method to return subtype (more specialized type). Besides, this overridden clone() within int[] "class" ha also its visibility changed from protected to public (increasing visibility also allowed while overriding).

Proof of concept:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };        
System.out.println((arr.clone()).getClass()); // class [I
System.out.println((arr.clone()).getClass().getCanonicalName()); //int[]
```

More experiments:

User-defined method with same signature as clone() within Object (see snippet below) gives compile error, unlike clone() in topmost snippet above. Also note, that in snippet below there is no difference, whether method returns int[] as "return arr" or "return (Object) arr"):

```
public class MyTest {

    static Object returns_arr_as_Object() {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
        return arr; // snippet don't change if add cast: (Object) arr
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object obj = returns_arr_as_Object(); // fine!

        int[] myarr;        
        myarr = returns_arr_as_Object(); // c.ERR! can't Object -> int[]
```

**BUT IF WE CHANGE RETURN TYPE OF returns_arr_as_Object() FROM Object to int[], the snippet compiles fine!**

Additional info:

> §4.3.1 of Java Language Specification: "arrays are objects" + "The
>   **supertype relation for array types is not the same as the superclass relation**. The direct supertype of Integer[] is Number[] according to
>   §4.10.3, but the direct superclass of Integer[] is Object according to
>   the Class object for Integer[] (§10.8). This does not matter in
>   practice, because **Object is also a superTYPE of all array types**."

Arrays are covariant (unlike parametrized generics, which are invariant), meaning that Integer[] IS Object[] (but not vice versa, and seems like it doesn't apply to int[] vs Object[])

Additional experiments:

Snippet 1:

```
int[] ar1 = { 1, 2 };
int[] ar2 = { 10, 20 };
Object obj = ar2; // now compiler knows that obj points to int[]
ar1 = obj; // c.ERR: cannot convert from Object to int[]
```

Snippet 2:

```
    int[] ar1 = { 1, 2 };
    int[] ar2 = { 10, 20 };
    Integer[] arInteger = { 10, 20 };

    Object[] objArr = ar2; // c.ERR: can't from int[] to Object[] 
    Object obj = ar2; // COMPILES!, but useless: obj[0] is c.ERR
    ar1 = obj; // c.ERR: cannot convert from Object to int[]
    arInteger = obj; // c.ERR: cannot convert from Object to Integer[]

    Object obj2 = arInteger;
    ar1 = obj2; // c.ERR: cannot convert from Object to int[]
    arInteger = obj2; // c.ERR: cannot convert from Object to Integer[]

    Object[] obj2Arr = arInteger; // COMPILES FINE !!!
    ar1 = obj2Arr; // c.ERR: can't convert from Object[] to int[]
    arInteger = obj2Arr; // c.ERR: can't from Object[] to Integer[]

    Object[] oArr = ar2; // c.ERR: cannot convert from int[] to Object[]
    oArr = arInteger; // COMPILES!
    System.out.println(oArr[0]); // output: 10
```

More links: [cast primitive array to Object and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252403/cast-primitive-array-to-object-and-back)

P.S. My compiler is Eclipse (NEON 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle [API docs for Object.clone() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) explicitly states the following, which totally explains everything:

> Note that all arrays are considered to implement the interface
>   Cloneable and that the return type of the clone method of an array
>   type T[] is T[] where T is any reference or primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler knows that `ar1.clone()` is specifically an `int[]`.  Thus it allows that assignment with no issue.

On the other hand, the compiler does not know whether or not `obj` is an `int[]`.  It will thus not allow that assignment without an explicit cast (which is you telling the compiler that you know what you're doing and this is intentional.)

Answer (score -2):

It's because int[] isn't an object, it's a datastructure which you can think of as a data type. Int[] isn't a class therefore when you create an int[] you are not creating an object. You are creating a variable with the int[] datatype.

Comment: This is wrong.  See the first sentence: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html.

Comment: an int[] **is** an object. Just execute `System.out.println((new int[0]) instanceof Object);`

Comment: "An object is a class instance **or an array**." - [Java Language Specification, Section 4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) (emphasis mine)